# How to delete a misnamed file on Android?

Tags: linux

I’ve a file called like `t0.t1 t2 t3` on my Android Device.

first it had a bad name from download and I tried to rename it. Something has to gone wrong. It was `o1.o2` before.

I tried to rename it to something else - only `o2` should be the same and *`t0-t3`* the name before the file ending

Now the name is like above, but without file ending.

[RootExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer&hl=en) shows me the file like above (first line)
the custom ROM file explorer `.o2`.

I cannot rename, move or delete it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could install [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) on your computer (part of the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)), plug in the device then use the adb shell to delete the offending file. Something along the lines of,

```
$> adb shell
your-android-device> rm '/path/to/file'
```

Comment: yes; I tried that via terminal emulator - no such file or directory (via `ls` I get `.o2` - also that doesn't work)

Comment: Can you list it with wildcards?  ls -la \*.o2\* (there should be stars before the . and after the two, the stackoverflow phone app is beating me atm :-))

Comment: I can list it with _normal_ ls, but then I get `.o2` (and I cannot delete it with this name)

Comment: I've created a file on my phone called '.o2 t1' and 'o2' and was able to delete both of them using ES File Explorer.